# AMP implementation on Shopify based Product Description Page

Tags: amp-html

Looking for possible solutions to get AMP implemented on my Shopify based Product Description Page. Currently, we are hitting one third party API. Response from this API helps to open the i-frame that contains jquery UI calendar on PDP page. To open this calendar we need to enter a valid zip code which hits the API and in response displays available delivery dates.

PDP Page requirements:

ZIP Code:- Input Field
Country specific ajax call for zip code validation to 3rd party API.
API returns Enable/Disable delivery dates, Delivery Location type,

Delivery Calendar:- Select Date Field
Jquery UI Calendar
Enable/Disable Date comes from 3rd party API according to ZIP Code
Shopify settings also implemented on PDP Page for Enable/Disable Date and Adding text on a specific date.

As of now I have been trying to implement AMP through below methods but was no success.

Q1. If I open my calendar in AMP i-frame, how will I get any selected value to the input field on my AMP Page?

Q2. When I enter zip-code I get a response from third party API, how can I pass this response to my calendar for opening possible delivery dates in AMP i-frame.

---

On PDP page we hit some third party APIs (using ajax request) in which we send product details along with a zip code where the product needs to be delivered and on the response from the API, we get dates on which delivery is possible. On the basis of the response dates, we enable/disable dates in the calendar.

Along with that internally we have made some settings in the Shopify admin to enable/disable some specific dates and put any extra Surcharge for some dates, we need to pass all these settings in the calendar.

Basically, all major functionality work with API's ajax request/response and on that basis the calendar dates arrange accordingly. Finally, when API response and settings are implemented on the calendar we pass user selected calendar date with other Fields values(ZIP Code, Quantity, Product Price) to the cart page.

Comment: Do you have an example URL (or even screenshot) of the page you're trying to convert? Is the problem on the Shopify side, or in the interaction with the 3P calendar/zipcode APIs?

Answer (score 0):

The best solution to quickly activate AMP for your Products and still allow customization is the [AMP for Shopify Plugin](https://apps.shopify.com/amp-google).  But to answer your questions:

1) Communicating from an iframe back to an AMP page is impossible.  The only communication message protocol AMP allows is an iframe resize message, which is built into the AMP Javascript on your original AMP page.  This allows a PostMessage to work from the embedded iframe, but only for resizing the frame, nothing else.

2) An AMP-form can submit AJAX data from your original page (or from your iframe).  But again, communicating from your original page to the embedded iframe is impossible.

An AMP plugin also can't solve these issues because, again, of their incompatibility with AMP itself.  Happy to answer any other questions if there's still confusion.